# How to replace attributes with HTML Element content(plain text) with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I making a form that will take contact info and send it to an email. It works expect the cities which I have more than 2000 options. The cities drop down sends the value, which is just a number. I want the form to send the city, which is HTML element content not the value number in the attribute. I do not want to replace the 2000 different values with the cities. I know a loop would the way to go but I don't know how to create it.

HTML -

`<option value="2" >Los Angeles - CA</option>`

PHP -

```
$city = $_REQUEST['city'] ;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
       mail( "$webmaster_email", "Submission", "$city,"From:$email" );
header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
```

Comment: Why a loop? Use an array.

Comment: how and where are the 2000 cities options stored?

Comment: I have a gigantic list of 2000 options

Comment: Are you willing to add Javascript to your page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to send the *text* and not the *value* from the `option`. Right?

I suggest you to create this element on your form: `<input type='hidden' id='city_name' name='city_name' />` to hold the `select` value with JavaScript when user select his desired option. Then, create and event on the `select` like this:

```
<select onchange="document.getElementById('city_name').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;">
```

So you'll have the `$_POST['city_name']` available on your PHP code.

Comment: Correct I want to capture the plain HTML text within the element. Then I want to send it to the email not a number because when the office gets the number they won't know what to do with it.

Comment: So that code will do it for you. I didn't tested it, but it should work. By the way, syntax highlight's showing that you have and error on your code in here `"$city,` fix that to this `"$city",` or you'll have a syntax error.

Comment: forgive my newest but is this all the Js I need in the head?<script type="text/javascript">
            onchange="document.getElementById('city_name').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;"
        </script>

Comment: Its not that way. Look my edit. The event goes on the `select` tag like this: `<select onchange="document.getElementById('city_name').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;">`

Answer (score 1):

Use an array! 
Example:

```
<?php
    $cities = array(
        '0' => 'New York - NY',
        '1' => '...'
        '2' => '...'
    );
    if (isset($cities[$_REQUEST['city']])) {
        $city = $cities[$_REQUEST['city']];
    } else {
        $city = $_REQUEST['city'];
    }

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        mail( "$webmaster_email", "Submission", "$city,"From:$email" );
        header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you produced that `<option>` list with something on the server, e.g. an array:

```
$locations = array(
   ...
   2 => 'Los Angeles - CA'
   ...
);
```

then you'd simply have

```
$place = $locations[$_REQUEST['city']];
```

to get the text for the option.

Alternatively, you embed the full city name in the option:

```
<option value="Los Angeles - CA">Lost Angeles - CA</option>
```

Comment: The question says he doesn't want to rewrite all the options in the second way.

Comment: @user2101421 where is this list? In your JS or HTML or on a database?

Comment: @barmar: doesn't matter. either there's a list of the options available to the code somewhere, or the html list has to be rewritten. The form will submit `2` as written in the OP's code, and there is NO way to translate that `2` into Los Angeles without some kind of lookup/translation system.